# Breaking express router into multiple files

Tags: javascript, express

[I googled this question](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20break%20an%20express%20router%20into%20different%20files) and was initially quite hopeful at the number of responses. That hopefulness quickly turned into disappointment as I read through the first 4 links, as well as the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) and could not find any viable resolutions to my inquiry. I want to break my routes into two files: One file for GET request and one file for POST request. Many articles on the internet hint at the ability to do this, or they state how to do it but in a very context specific application. Can someone please provide a generalized and fully complete way to break an Express router into multiple files with code examples?

**router.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var models = require('../db/models.js');
var util = require('../core/utilities.js');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/messages', function (req, res) {
  util.log('RECEIVED a GET request', req.query);

  models.retrieveMarks(req.query)
    .then(function(msg) {
      util.log('SENT message array to user', msg);
      res.status(200);
      res.send(msg);
    }, function(err) {
      util.log('SENT error code to user', err);
      res.sendStatus(400);
    });
});

router.post('/messages', function(req, res) {
  util.log('RECEIVED a POST request', req.body);

  //input: {x: float, y: float, z: float, message: string, userToken: string}
  models.createMessage(req.body)
    .then(function(msg) {
      util.log('SENT success code to user', msg);
      res.sendStatus(201);
    }, function(err) {
      util.log('SENT error code to user', err);
      res.sendStatus(400);
    });
});

//input: {userToken: string}
router.post('/usertoken', function (req, res) {
  var token = req.body.userToken;
  util.log('RECEIVED a new user token from user', token);

  models.createUser(token)
    .then(function(user) {
      util.log('SENT success code to user', user);
      res.sendStatus(201);
    }, function(err) {
      util.log('SENT error code to user', err);
      res.sendStatus(400);
    });
});

//input: {messageId: string, userToken: string}
router.post('/upvote', function (req, res) {
  util.log('RECEIVED upvote request', req.body);
  models.createVote(+req.body.messageId, req.body.userToken);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

//input: {messageId: string, message: string}
router.post('/comment', function (req, res) {
  util.log("RECEIVED comment", req.body);
  models.createComment(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

router.get('/comment', function(req, res) {
  util.log('RECEIVED a GET request', req.query);
  models.retrieveComments(+req.query.messageId)
    .then(function(comments) {
      util.log('SENT comments to user', comments);
      res.status(200);
      res.send(comments);
    }, function(err) {
      util.log('SENT error code to user', err);
      res.sendStatus(400);
    });
});

router.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../landing'));

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution, with a shared router:

```
// router.js
var router = express.Router();
require('./get-routes')(router);
require('./post-routes')(router);

// get-routes.js
module.exports = function(router) {
  router.get(...);
};

// post-routes.js
module.exports = function(router) {
  router.post(...);
};
```

Another solution, with nested routers:

```
// router.js
var router = module.exports = require('express').Router();
router.use(require('./get-routes'));
router.use(require('./post-routes'));

// get-routes.js
var router = module.exports = require('express').Router();

router.get(...);

// post-routes.js
var router = module.exports = require('express').Router();

router.post(...);
```

Comment: I don't understand how this will compile. For the first solution I'm getting: 'TypeError: require(...) is not a function'

Comment: Where is app defined for the second solution?

Comment: @etayluz that's an Express app (`var app = express()`)

Comment: Thanks @robertklep; however, that `var app = express()` is typically declared in a server.js or app.js file that is executed as `node app` or `node server`. How is router.js included or executed in the second solution's context?

Comment: @etayluz I guess that in the second example, `router.js` should be called `app.js` or `server.js` (i.e. the top-level file that sets up Express). Either that, or instead of `app` you could instantiate another `express.Router`.

Comment: Thanks again @robertklep; I just don't understand why routes should be laid out in the top-level file with all other app settings - seems like something that should be delegated to a separate router.js file as you've suggested. If you could kindly write a third solution that explain how to setup app.js, router.js, and then route1.js, route2.js, route3.js - that would be terrific!

Comment: @etayluz see edit (it doesn't explain the full down-to-the-app-level setup, but it does show what I probably intended to write 2 years ago). In the end it comes down to preference a lot, there isn't necessarily one good way to implement this.